# Want to calculate the Age of a Date Field in a Table in Access DB

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that has a [DateOpened] field and an [Age] Field. I want the age field to auto calculate the age difference of the Date open field. the Date Open field is in a Date mm\dd\yyyy format. When i try to use the DateDiff function in the Age field i get an error can find the date open field.

```
=DateDiff('d',[Date Opened],Date())
```

error: The database engine does not recognize either the field'Date Opened' in a validation expression, or the default value in the table.

Any suggestions. I am not wanting to use a query to calculate the Age Field. However, if i have to how would i set that field calculation in the Query?

Comment: You say *I have a table that has a **[DateOpened]** field*, but your code sample uses **[Date Opened]**. See the difference yet?

Comment: Sorry a typo on my part

Comment: It should "I have a table that has a [Date Opened] field, but your code sample uses [Date Opened]."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start a new query and build the correct formula there, as its easier to build & test formulas in the query builder.

It will mean putting something like the following in as an extra (parameterised / calculated) query field:

```
Age: DateDiff('d',[DateOpened],Now())
```

I doubt you'll be able to transfer that to the table itself though, as calculated fields in tables are quite restricted as to the kind of functions that are allowed. I don't think DateDiff is allowed.

Best practice would be to set up a query through which to view & interact with your main table, which adds on any calculated fields, e.g:

```
SELECT Table1.*, DateDiff('d',[DateOpened],Now()) AS Age FROM Table1;
```

I usually follow a convention with table & query names as follows:

**tbl_FOO** - holds the raw (uncalculated) data

**qry_FOO** - passes through all (*), and supplements that with any required calculated fields